# How to calculate output of this neural network?

Tags: self-study, neural-networks

[image: Neural network image]

I am sure this is a pretty easy question for someone well versed with neural networks but it has had me running round the bends.

While I understand how this is to be done in principle, i.e. readjustment of weights according to the thresholds, but a solution or atleast a partial solution will be highly helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Because this is a textbook or homework question, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: I think it is pretty straightforward. But I find the input values confusing. Since "high" =0; is "low" = -1 ?. Is "yes" = 1? and "no" = 0? ,what is "normal" equal to ? If this is made clear I can take a shot at solving it.

And you say that you have to readjust the weights according to the thresholds. I think this is not correct. Since this is just a feedforward network, your weights are fixed (-5,6,3,...). 

I am not "well versed" in NNs but I read http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html which gives you some basic info how to do this.

Comment: @Ojtwist thanks, the first value is 1, second 0, for example for intensity={normal,high}, normal=1, high=0 ,  for entropy = {high,low} , high = 1, low = 0, for contrast ={yes,no}, yes=1, no=0  - I believe there isn't a -1 involved at all. Would be great if you do take the shot :)

Comment: follow this tutorial its very simple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK-yg4D_elE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my best guess based on http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html.

The input is a linear activation $f(x)=x$ function which means that the input value will be in the first layer. So this means that :

- Node 1 = 1
- Node 2 = 0
- Node 3 = 1
- Node 4 = 0

In order to calculate the hidden nodes, we use the simple perceptron rule $\sum\limits_{j}{w_j x_j}$ where $w$ are the weights written next to the links and $x$ are the values from the nodes in the previous layer and $j$ the amount of nodes in the previous layer

**Which results in node 5**:

$(-1*5) + (0*3)+ (1*2) +(0*4) = -5+2= -3$ (so multiply weights with the input)
Now we have a binary activation rule, which is just check if it is bigger than 0 or not. 
$-3<0$ so this means that this will be a 0.

**Node 6**:

$(1*6)+(0*-1)+(1*-2)+(0*5)= 6-2 = 4$ again we apply the binary threshold, and $4>0$ so this means this will become a 1.

**Node 7**: We take the output we just calculated and multiply it with the weight to get the output:

$(0*-1)+(2*1)=2$ which is larger than 0 so the output of the network is 1

I am not sure this is correct. But I hope it will at least help you to see someone else's interpretation of the exercise.

Comment: Ah...Merci :) that is superb.... Thankyou very much for your time and effort...this will help a lot!!! I acccepted the answer

Comment: I know this is old but before reading this answer I did it all on paper and independently got the same results. So I think this is correct.

Comment: Having also a bias, should the steps be calculated in the same way but just adding `+b` of that node in each step? Shouldn't we use the `1/(1+e^-(x*w +b))` ? Why is `x*w +b` used without the rest?